# How to start another activity after all views shown

Tags: android

I have a stub activity with progress bar and two labels, and another activity, that may do heavy task (initialize sqlite db from xml resources at first start).

I need start second activity after progress bar and labels are shown.

I'm trying

```
stubLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        if (progress.getHeight() <= 0 || progress.getWidth() <= 0) return;
        if (label1.getHeight() <= 0 || label1.getWidth() <= 0) return;
        if (label2.getHeight() <= 0 || label2.getWidth() <= 0) return;

        stubLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), SongListActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

But I see empty screen while heavy activity is starting.
What am I doing wrong?

---

I've already found solution myself.

I've found that system create db not on get instance of db helper, but on first query.

The solution is to init db in AsyncTask and start the second activity on post execute:

```
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> initDbTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
    SongDBHelper helper;
    String[] artists;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        helper = SongDBHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext(), getResources());
        artists = helper.getArtistList();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), SongListActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};

initDbTask.execute(null, null, null);
```

Comment: This solution should be in a self-answer, not as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may call your activity with progress bar `SplashActivity` that shows on start up. In this activity you should do your heavy task (sql initialize) in an `AsyncTask`. When the `AsyncTask` is done, just call your other activity to show.

Some stuff of code:

## `SplashActivity`

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_activity);

    new AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>(){
        @Override
        protected Param doInBackground(Params... params) {
            // DO YOUR SQL STUFF HERE
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Param aParam) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            // DO YOUR NEXT STEP HERE AFTER SQL TASK DONE
        }
    }.execute(..some parameters..); 
}
```

Comment: You may vote or accept my answer if anyone else has same problem and found this :). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
@Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus) {
       super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
       if (hasFocus ){
         // start your new activity
       }
    }
```

This method is called when window receives focus and this is after all the views are shown.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not works. I see empty screen while second activity starting.